# Overlapping memory addresses in x64 C function from PInvoke

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

We have a PInvoke as follows:

```
[DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "ExternalName", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr ExternalFunction(IntPtr state, IntPtr inputData, int inputIndex, int inputLength, int tailLength);
```

With the `C` declaration as follows:

```
void * __cdecl ExernalName(void* state, void* inputData, int32_t inputIndex, int32_t inputLength, int32_t tailLength);
```

When running the .NET application as x86, it works fine. However, when run in AnyCPU on a x64 machine, the memory addresses of the function arguments are off.

For example purposes, lets assume state = 1, inputData = 2, inputIndex = 3, and inputLength = 4. Both State and InputData are void*, so they should be 8 bytes long whereas the rest should be 4 bytes.

If I set a breakpoint in the function, the value is state is 2. Lets assume the memory address of state is determined to be 0x00000008.

The memory address of inputData comes back as 0x0000000C, inputIndex as 0x00000010, and inputLength as 0x00000014.

First problem, why is the memory address of inputData 4 bytes after state and inputIndex 4 bytes after inputData? Shouldn't state and inputData be 8 bytes each?

Second problem, if I actually check the memory addresses of where the values *should* be, they're there, but where is 1? 1 is at 0x00000000.

How does this even happen? What are my bad assumptions and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the imported DLL compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit? Trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process could cause strange things like this.

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons Loading 32-bit DLL into 64-bit process is usually not possible and results in bad image format exception

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Code in question is fine. That pinvoke is correct. Show the code that you use to identify what you think is a problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was inspecting the variables from the debugger. When they weren't what they should have been, I started probing memory addresses using the intermediate window.

Comment: It has started working since I did a clean and rebuild. No idea what happened to begin with...

Comment: Variables will be passed as you'd expect if this really is the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by calling conventions in x64 mode. Actually, there is no cdecl, no stdcall, no fastcall in x64 - these directives are ignored.

In Windows, there is the only one calling convention in x64 mode - Microsoft x64 calling convention. In this convention, the first four parameters are passed in registers rather than by stack if the size of each parameter is 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes. At the same time, 32 bytes is reserved for debugging purpose.

It means that taking the addresses of input parameters and reading its values directly from the stack is meaningless.

Try printing the values on console instead of watching its values in the debugger. Also check the compiler options that may force using cdecl instead of default x64 calling convention.

Comment: The registers were wrong too. The register that was supposed to contain the first variable had the second.

Anywho, rebuilding the library in question managed to fix it. Whatever "it" was....